# Avrdude unable to write - C232HM-DDHSL-0 Linux Mint

Tags: linux, avr, ftdi, avrdude

I've been trying to program my ATmega644p using a C232HM-DDHSL-0 programmer which is based on the FT232H chip.

I've edited the .avrduderc in my home directory to include the following, which I've adapted from /etc/avrdude.conf:

```
     programmer 
     id   = "C232HM"; 
     desc   = "C232HM-MPSSE"; 
     type   = avrftdi; 
     usbvid     = 0x0403; 
     # Note: This PID is reserved for generic H devices and 
     # should be programmed into the EEPROM 
     #  usbpid     = 0x8A48; 
     usbpid    = 0x6014; // changed from 0x6010 after checking "lsusb" 
     usbdev = "A"; 
     usbvendor  = ""; 
     usbproduct = ""; 
     usbsn      = ""; 
     #ISP-signals // Modified according to datasheet 
     reset  = 5; 
     sck    = 2; 
     mosi   = 3; 
     miso   = 4; 
     ;
```

I've been able to communicate with the MCU using avrdude using

```
     sudo avrdude -c 2232HIO -p m644p -P /dev/ttyUSB0
```

where the output to terminal is:

```
     Unknown type 6 (0x6) //Remainder pins - 1,2,7,8,9,10 not declared 
     Unknown type 6 (0x6) 
     Unknown type 6 (0x6) 
     Unknown type 6 (0x6) 
     Unknown type 6 (0x6) 
     Unknown type 6 (0x6) 


     avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions 

     Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.01s 

     avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e960a 

     avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK 

     avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Ouput with -vvvv option enabled: 
http://pastebin.com/z3K8RYJP

However when I try to flash a simple .hex file, it stalls while writing flash:

```
    Unknown type 6 (0x6) 
    Unknown type 6 (0x6) 
    Unknown type 6 (0x6) 
    Unknown type 6 (0x6) 
    Unknown type 6 (0x6) 
    Unknown type 6 (0x6) 

    avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions 

    Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.01s 

    avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e960a 
    avrdude: NOTE: FLASH memory has been specified, an erase cycle will be performed 
    To disable this feature, specify the -D option. 
    avrdude: erasing chip 
    avrdude: reading input file "int1.hex" 
    avrdude: input file int1.hex auto detected as Intel Hex 
    avrdude: writing flash (164 bytes): 

    Writing |
```

Output with the -vvvv option enabled: 
http://pastebin.com/EmmuCsxN

I've also installed the D2XX drivers from FTDI and followed the steps as outlined in this guide, but to no avail: (see comment for links)

It seems that I'm unable to write to the MCU, so my first guess would be I've mis-configured the programmer. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Just noticed that I was using the different command to communicate with the MCU :(

EDIT2: I fixed it using this config:

```
    programmer
    id  = "C232HM";
    desc    = "C232HM-MPSSE";
    type    = avrftdi;
    usbvid     = 0x0403;
    # Note: This PID is reserved for generic H devices and 
    # should be programmed into the EEPROM
    #  usbpid     = 0x8A48;
    usbpid    = 0x6014;
    usbdev = "A";
    usbvendor  = "";
    usbproduct = "";
    usbsn      = "";
    #ISP-signals 
    reset  = 4;
    sck    = 1;
    mosi   = 2;
    miso   = 3;
    ;
```

Comment: [D2XX FTdi Linux guide](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_220_FTDI_Drivers_Installation_Guide_for_Linux%20.pdf),


[C232HM-DDHSL-0 Datasheet](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/Cables/DS_C232HM_MPSSE_CABLE.PDF)